# Error: Failed to make request to https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/releases.json firebase init error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, npm, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

Iam trying to host a react website(created with npx create-react-app) on firebase, after logging in when I run firebase init command it gives A error, complete log:

> ```
> > ? Are you ready to proceed? Yes ? Which Firebase features do you want
> > to set up for this directory? Press Space to select features, then
> > Enter  ? Which Firebase features do you want to set up for this
> > directory? Press Space to select features, then Enter  ? Which
> > Firebase features do you want to set up for this directory? Press
> > Space to select features, then Enter  ? Which Firebase features do you
> > want to set up for this directory? Press Space to select features,
> > then Enter ? Which Firebase features do you want to set up for this
> > directory? Press Space to select features, then Enter ? Which Firebase
> > features do you want to set up for this directory? Press Space to
> > select features, then Enter  to confirm your choices. Hosting:
> > Configure files for Firebase Hosting and (optionally) set up GitHub
> > Action de ploys
> > 
> > === Project Setup
> > 
> > First, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project.
> > You can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add,
> > but for now we'll just set up a default project.
> > 
> > ? Please select an option: Use an existing project ? Select a default
> > Firebase project for this directory: genxclub-55b73 (genxclub) i 
> > Using project genxclub-55b73 (genxclub)
> > 
> > === Hosting Setup
> > 
> > Your public directory is the folder (relative to your project
> > directory) that will contain Hosting assets to be uploaded with
> > firebase deploy. If you have a build process for your assets, use your
> > build's output directory.
> > 
> > ? What do you want to use as your public directory? build ? Configure
> > as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? Yes ? Set up
> > automatic builds and deploys with GitHub? No
> > 
> > Error: Failed to make request to
> > https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/releases.json
> ```

I also tried doing firebase init --debug, it gives me this error:

```
[2021-08-20T07:48:26.003Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/releases.json [none]
[2021-08-20T07:48:26.810Z] FetchError: request to https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/releases.json failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Swapnil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1461:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at ClientRequest.emit (domain.js:470:12)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:475:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (domain.js:470:12)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)

Error: Failed to make request to https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/releases.json
```

I also tried doing npm audit and npm audit --force, it didn't work

my Files:

[image]

Comment: Looks like some network issue. Have you tried using any other ISP ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj i dont think that it's network issue, I have good internet speed

Comment: It's not about the speed always. You ISP maybe having issues resolving that domain.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I also opened the domain in browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

node wasn't allowing me to use internet when I was unauthorized

I solved the error using running this command:

```
set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```